# How is it that an unsigned integer array can contain a negative integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, unsigned

I wrote this piece of code just to see what would happen if I put a negative integer into an unsigned integer array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    unsigned int array[4];
    array[0]=4;
    array[1]=4;
    array[2]=2;
    array[3]=-2;

    cout << array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + array[3] << endl;

    unsigned int b;
    b=-2;
    cout << b <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting integer overflow to occur in both the cases. However, only in the second case that actually happened. In the first case, everything behaved as if it were an oridinary integer array, not an unsigned integer array. So what exactly is happening that's causing this anomalous behaviour. My compiler is gcc 4.8 in cases that's of any importance. Thank you for your help. EDIT: Here's th output on my computer

```
8
4294967294
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: Integer overflow *does* occur.  It just happens to be the kind that you are happy with.  This is not guaranteed to work, it is merely common.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the unsigned overflow and signed->unsigned conversion rules are defined in such a way that the first result is guaranteed to be 8, and the second result is guaranteed to be 1 less than the maximum unsigned int. It's *signed* overflow that does crazy shit.

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic in C++ is modulo 2^N, guaranteed.

Comment: This should become clearer to you if you output the actual values of `array[0]` etc. not just their sum.

Comment: @starsplusplus I copied his code and printed out the array values instead. I get 4, 4, 2, -2. This is not consistent with the overflow theory advocated by everyone on here. How could this be?

Comment: Ah ok, I figured it out. The issue was I was using a range based for loop with a signed integer to print it out. Changed to unsigned int and everything works as expected!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an integer overflow. Here is the reason ( the numbers are converted to unsigned int)

```
 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 // -2
+0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 //+ 4
-------------------------------------------
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 //= 2
+0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 //+ 4
-------------------------------------------
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 //= 6
+0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 //+ 2
-------------------------------------------
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 //= 8 -> the result
```

Answer (score 1):

For the signed integers, the last bit is used to hold the sign value. So in your case, when you assign a negative integer to an unsigned integer, the last bit is taken up to represent the number rather than the sign value.

Negative numbers are usually represented in 2's complement form. So

```
11111110  is represented as −1 if signed 
11111110  is represented as 254 if unsigned
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do (assuming unsigned int is uint32_t):

```
array[0] = 4;
array[1] = 4;
array[2] = 2;
array[3] = -2; // You store 4294967294 here
```

And here `array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + array[3]` is equal to `4294967304` which don't fit in an uint32_t `0x1 0000 0008` which result in `8`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `-2` to `unsigned int` results in the value `4294967294` (since `unsigned int` is 32 bits in the C++ implementation you're using).

`unsigned int` arithmetic is carried out modulo `4294967296` (or in general `UINT_MAX+1`). Hence in `unsigned int`, 4 + 4 + 2 + 4294967294 is 8.

Technically according to the standard this is not called "overflow", because the standard defines the result to depend only on the value of `UINT_MAX`. Overflow is the undefined behavior when signed integer arithmetic exceeds its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For signed integer, 31st bit is treated as sign bit (assuming 4 byte is integer size). For unsigned integers, there is no sign bit at all, i.e. each bit is contributes to the absolute value

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the result of (defined) unsigned integer overflow. Your -2 value becomes a very large unsigned integer, which when added to another unsigned integer, causes an overflow (the result is larger than the largest possible `unsigned int` value) with the *effect* that the result is 2 smaller than the other unsigned integer.

Eg:

```
unsigned int a = -2;
unsigned int b = 4;
unsigned int c = a + b; // result will be 2!
```